# What is the drawback of not deleting inactive device tokens returned by APNS feedback service?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

The obvious problem is I will be attempting to send push to inactive devices that won't receive push anyway, therefore wasting my traffic and possibly degrading performance.

But let's say I am willing to temporarily live with this because I need to fix other issues first. Is this OK? I am worried Apple may cut you off if you don't take care of it and keep trying to send push to non-existent devices. More specifically, I don't know how to interpret this sentence in their documentation:

> APNs monitors providers for their diligence in checking the feedback service and refraining from sending remote notifications to nonexistent apps on devices.

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)

Comment: Honestly, this is so easy to do, either yourself, or by using a third-party push provider, that I think you should do that from stage 1. If you are not able to do that, I am afraid you may miss other important features as well (error checking, detecting bad tokens, etc).

Comment: Agreed with Mickaël however

Comment: Could you elaborate about the other important features? I didn't understand.

Comment: Well, if you read the Apple push service protocol, you see for example, that you need to process errors response from Apple. That's just an example, but it shows that running a reliable push server is not as easy as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do start getting massive amounts of inactive devices that you're pushing too, then Apple will send you a warning, that's when you will switch priorities.

Comment: do they email me? Or can i see it on itunes connect?